# Excel VBA to multiply cell if another cell contains text

Tags: excel, vba

I do know the formula but not sure how to translate into VBA.

Need a VBA script to do the following.

If cell D contains Debit, then value in F multiply -1
If cell D contains Credit, then value in F multiply 1

Loop until last row.

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this macro:

```
Sub subMultiply()
    For Each cel In Range("D1:D" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row)
        If cel.Value = "Debit" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = Val(cel.Offset(0, 2)) * (-1)
        ElseIf cel.Value = "Credit" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = Val(cel.Offset(0, 2)) * 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ! That helps a lot ! Appreciate it

Comment: You should then accept my answer. Tick the answer as green.